# Font used by Desmos?

Tags: fonts

I was curious if anyone knows the font used by the Desmos graphing calculator. All the formulas are formatted as LaTeX, so I wanted to know if there was a way to use this font in my own documents. It seems at first glance like standard Computer Modern, but upon closer inspection as you can see the "w" and "v" characters are rendered in a style that makes them pointier so that they are much easier to distinguish from omega and u respectively (and imo they just look a bit more pleasant). Here is a side-by-side comparison for context.

Computer Modern: [image: standard round w times omega over standard round v times u]
Desmos Font:[image: pointy w times omega over pointy v times u]

(This is my first time making a post on the site, so apologies if I have made any mistakes!)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I can't identify the font, but the pointy "v" is not a good idea -- it's too similar to a nu.  That's the reason Computer Modern has a rounded "v", and the "w" was reshaped to match.

Comment: Which part of Desmos are you referring to? The online graph editor does actually not use LaTeX to display math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly the font you're looking for (Desmos may use a non-freely available font), but `newtx` may serve your needs and is included in the standard TeX installation. Be warned though (as Barbara Beeton notes) that `\nu` should not be used in this font.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\[
\frac{w\omega}{\nu vu}
\]
\emph{A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which part of Desmos you are referring to, but the online graph drawing tool uses Times New Roman in the formula editor which can be found out if you inspect the stylesheet of the website.

You can also see that what is displayed is not really LaTeX but plain HTML. So, this answer is necessarily off-topic.

[image]

Comment: I did not realize that, I had assumed it uses LaTeX because copy-pasting the formulas entered into the graph editor shows them in LaTeX format, i.e. if I were to copy what you have in your editor here, I would get `f\left(x\right)=\frac{wx}{vy}`. So then is it possible for an application to use the LaTeX syntax without being LaTeX?

Comment: @Julia Syntax has nothing to do with how things are processed internally. It is just an interface between the user and a program. Of course, typically a program uses a specific syntax, but virtually any programing language can be used to interpret (parse) any syntax in any way. Alike, you can generate LaTeX syntax with any programming language from any input. The Demos interface probably uses JavaScript to convert the input to LaTeX syntax which is then copied to the user's clipboard. Another example of software that uses LaTeX syntax without actually using TeX to render math is MathJax.

Comment: Given that it is used for different programs, is this syntax still just called "LaTeX syntax," or is there a specific name for it?

Comment: @Julia I'd say, "LaTeX syntax" is fine. It is just important to understand that the output is likely to be different if the rendering is not done with TeX but with some other software.